# Caching strategies for entities and collections

Tags: .net, design-patterns, caching, architecture, scalability

We currently have an application framework in which we automatically cache both entities and collections of entities at the business layer (using .NET cache). So the method GetWidget(int id) checks the cache using a key GetWidget_Id_{0} before hitting the database, and the method GetWidgetsByStatusId(int statusId) checks the cache using GetWidgets_Collections_ByStatusId_{0}. If the objects are not in the cache they are retrieved from the database and added to the cache.

This approach is obviously quick for read scenarios, and as a blanket approach is quick for us to implement, but requires large numbers of cache keys to be purged when CRUD operations are carried out on entities. Obviously as additional methods are added this impacts performance and the benefits of caching diminish.

I'm interested in alternative approaches to handling caching of collections. I know that NHibernate caches a list of the identifiers in the collection rather than the actual entities. Is this an approach other people have tried - what are the pros and cons?

In particular I am looking for options that optimise performance and can be implemented automatically through boilerplate generated code (we have our own code generation tool). I know some people will say that caching needs to be done by hand each time to meet the needs of the specific situation but I am looking for something that will get us most of the way automatically.

Comment: Opinion questions should be on Programmers.StackExchange: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CAbbott I think this question meets the guidance in the faq for questions - it relates to "a specific programming problem" and is answerable.

Comment: I would say that you're not asking a "practical programming question" i.e. "I've written *X* and it isn't working", rather you're soliciting *opinions* on alternative approaches to spark discussion.

Comment: I am interested in how you manage the keys (int id).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is really.

But take a look at redis, it s a data structure cache you can use that.

based on your definition, you are storing GetWidget_Id_{0} , why you doing that? first of all you can have your own cache, and you can write a in memory cache container rather easily.

```
interface ICache<K,V>{
   put(K,V)
   V get(K)
   delete(K)
}

class CacheContainer<K,V> : ICache<K,V>
{

   ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> _cache = new ....

   put impl..
   get impl..
   delete impl..

   purge..


}
```

you can extend this and have LRU, LFU,  any sort of caching algorithm in your subclasses.

As for storing collections, same idea with storing items as a list or set.

Look at redis really to understand in memory/cached collections. once you understand the concepts, look at caching algorithms

Hope this helps.